# Enforce a "at least one of two fields should be present" rule in Circe

Tags: json, scala, circe

I'm writing a Circe parser where the schema requires that at least one of two fields is set. This is quite specific and it doesn't seem to be a way to do it easily with Circe API.

Let's call our fields `text` and `html`.

I tried already to create a class, let's call it `Content`, add it to the general model as a single parameter and raise an exception in the constructor if both its fields (text and html) are None. The problem is how to define the decoder, because if I do something like this

```
implicit val decodeContent: Decoder[ItemContent] =
    Decoder.forProduct2("text", "html")(Content.apply)
```

it requires both fields to be present anyway.

What I would like would be to have a decoder that, if the field is missing, pass a None to the `Content.apply` but I don't think this is the expected behaviour.

Otherwise there should be a totally different solution but I cannot think of one.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Decoder#emap`:

```
import io.circe._, parser._

case class ItemContent(text: Option[String], html: Option[String])

object ItemContent {
  implicit val decoder =
    Decoder.forProduct2("text", "html")(ItemContent.apply).emap {
      case ItemContent(None, None) => Left("Neither text nor html is present")
      case x                       => Right(x)
    }
}

assert {
  decode[ItemContent]("{}").isLeft &&
  decode[ItemContent]("""{"html": "foo"}""") == Right(
    ItemContent(None, Some("foo"))) &&
  decode[ItemContent]("""{"text": "bar"}""") == Right(
    ItemContent(Some("bar"), None)) &&
  decode[ItemContent]("""{"html": "foo", "text": "bar"}""") == Right(
    ItemContent(Some("bar"), Some("foo")))
}
```

[Runnable version](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ov3anZtkQHqanU0FMZyUYA)

---

To avoid specifying other fields it is possible to use semi-automatic derivation as a base:

```
import io.circe._, parser._, io.circe.generic.semiauto._

case class ItemContent(text: Option[String],
                       html: Option[String],
                       other: Int,
                       fields: String)

object ItemContent {
  implicit val decoder =
    deriveDecoder[ItemContent].emap { ic =>
      if (ic.text.isEmpty && ic.html.isEmpty)
        Left("Both `text` and `html` are missing")
      else Right(ic)
    }
}
```

[Runnable version](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/OHiVvO6STkO3qXdQDB9ArQ)

Comment: uuuh, very interesting, I will try it.

Comment: the problem with this is that it's trying to parse something of the form 

{ "content" : {"content_text":"abc"}}

while I need to have "content_text" and "content_html" in the root, together with other fields. This way I'm treating it like a nested object while my goal is to parse just those two field this way and treat the others normally.

The whole structure has many fields and I want to parse the others with the automatic derivation. Do you think it's possible?

Comment: @Chobeat you can start with derived decoder and add your validation on top of its result. I've updated the answer

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. Your answers made me understand a lot more on how this library should be used.